# How to solve error "ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead: array=13."?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, machine-learning

I am trying to predict the class of pupils based on their age everything is good so far but the error I showed above keeps on showing.

Since I am new to machine learning in python and this is my first linear regression model, I would prefer simple solutions that do not involve classes and objects.

Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pylab as pl
from sklearn import linear_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

file = pd.read_csv('age and class cs version.csv')


age = file[['Age ']]
classes = file[['Class']]

age_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(age)
classes_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(classes)


regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
model = regr.fit(age_dataframe,classes_dataframe)

new_age = 13

print(model.predict(new_age))
```

And here is the data from the csv file

```
Age   Class
7      1
11      5
14      9
14      8
15     10
16     12
17     12
15      8
9      3
```

Comment: `print(model.predict([[new_age]]))`

Comment: Please post the full error trace (not here, update your post).

Comment: You might want to to check the shapeof the input. whether they are (some_number, ) or (number, number).

Answer (score 0):

maybe try:

```
print(model.predict([[new_age]]))
```